# Pass a javascript variable value into input type hidden value

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to assign value of product of two integer numbers into a hidden field already in the html document.
I was thinking about getting the value of a javascript variable and then passing it on a input type hidden.
I'm having a hard time to explain but this is how it should work:

## Script Example

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function product(a,b){
      return a*b;
 }
 </script>
```

above computes the product and i want the product to be in hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="[return value from product function]">
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You could give your hidden field an id:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myField" value="" />
```

and then when you want to assign its value:

```
document.getElementById('myField').value = product(2, 3);
```

Make sure that you are performing this assignment after the DOM has been fully loaded, for example in the `window.load` event.

Answer (score 13):

if you already have that hidden input :

```
function product(a, b) {
   return a * b;
}
function setInputValue(input_id, val) {
    document.getElementById(input_id).setAttribute('value', val);
}
```

if not, you can create one, add it to the body and then set it's value :

```
function addInput(val) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    input.setAttribute('value', val);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

And then you can use(depending on the case) :

```
addInput(product(2, 3)); // if you want to create the input
// or
setInputValue('input_id', product(2, 3));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do that like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function product(a,b)
     {
     return a*b;
     }
    document.getElementById('myvalue').value = product(a,b);
 </script>

 <input type="hidden" value="THE OUTPUT OF PRODUCT FUNCTION" id="myvalue">
```

Answer (score 3):

Hidden Field :

```
<input type="hidden" name="year" id="year">
```

Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var year = new Date();
     document.getElementById("year").value=(year.getFullYear());
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this jQuery page for some interesting examples of how to play with the value attribute, and how to *call* it:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Otherwise - if you want to use jQuery rather than javascript in passing variables to an input of any kind, use the following to ***set*** the value of the input on an event `click()`, `submit()` et al:

on some event; assign or ***set*** the value of the input:

```
$('#inputid').val($('#idB').text());
```

where:

```
<input id = "inputid" type = "hidden" />

<div id = "idB">This text will be passed to the input</div>
```

Using such an approach, make sure the html input does not already specify a value, or a disabled attribute, obviously.

Beware the differences betwen `.html()` and `.text()` when dealing with html forms.

Answer (score 1):

add some id for an input

```
var multi = product(2,3);
document.getElementById('id').value=multi;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function product(x,y)
  {
   return x*y;
  }
 document.getElementById('myvalue').value = product(x,y);
 </script>

 <input type="hidden" value="THE OUTPUT OF PRODUCT FUNCTION" id="myvalue">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//prompts for input in javascript
test=prompt("Enter a value?","some string");

//passes javascript to a hidden field.
document.getElementById('myField').value = test;

//prompts for input in javascript
test2=prompt("Enter a value?","some string2");

//passes javascript to a hidden field
document.getElementById('myField').value = test2;

//prints output
document.write("hello, "+test+test2;
```

now this is confusing but this should work...

Comment: Please try to be less confusing in your answers in future :)