# Having issue passing a localStorage value to an input field

Tags: javascript, html

Okay guys, so I'm having an issue trying to pass a value that is stored in local storage over into an input field. I found this other thread, ([Pass a javascript variable value into input type hidden value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764154/pass-a-javascript-variable-value-into-input-type-hidden-value)) that showed how to do it, but it's still not working for me and I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. My entire code is down below, but i have separated it out to make it easier to get to the parts that actually matter.

```
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Location details</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script type="text/javascript">
```

This is where I'm trying to pass the stored values into the fields but have not luck.

```
    document.getElementById("plat").value = localStorage.latitude;
    document.getElementById("plon").value = localStorage.longitude;

    function fileSelected() {            
        var file = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0];
        if (file) {
            var fileSize = 0;
            if (file.size > 1024 * 1024) {
                fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
            }
            else {
                fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
            }

            document.getElementById("fileName").innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
            document.getElementById("fileSize").innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
            document.getElementById("fileType").innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
        }
    }

    function uploadFile() {
        var id = new formData();
        id.append("fileUpload", document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCancelled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "snap.php");
        xhr.send(id);
    }

    function uploadProgress(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            document.getElementById("progressNumber").innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("progressNumber").innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
        }
    }

    //==================================================================
    // These events are raised when the server sends back a response
    //==================================================================
    function uploadComplete(evt) {

        alert(evt.target.responseText);
    }

    function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("Therew as an error attempting to upload the file.");
    }

    function uploadCancelled(evt) {
        alert("The upload has been cancelled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <div>
    <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="scripts/snap.php">
```

Here are my input fields. They look fine to me.

> ```
>        <p>
>             <input id="plat" type="text" value="" />
>             <input id="plon" type="hidden" value="" />
>         </p>
>         <div class="row">
>             <label for="fileUpload">Select an image to Upload</label><br />
>             <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" />
>         </div>
>         <div id="filename"></div>
>         <div id="fileSize"></div>    
>         <div id="fileType"></div>
>         <div class="row">
>             <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />
>         </div>
>         <div id="progressNumber"></div>
>     </form>
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code you are calling script before the dom content loads:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById("plat").value = localStorage.latitude;
        document.getElementById("plon").value = localStorage.longitude;
    }, false);


    function fileSelected() {
        var file = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0];
        if (file) {
            var fileSize = 0;
            if (file.size > 1024 * 1024) {
                fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
            }
            else {
                fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
            }

            document.getElementById("fileName").innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
            document.getElementById("fileSize").innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
            document.getElementById("fileType").innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
        }
    }

    function uploadFile() {
        var id = new formData();
        id.append("fileUpload", document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCancelled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "snap.php");
        xhr.send(id);
    }

    function uploadProgress(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            document.getElementById("progressNumber").innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("progressNumber").innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
        }
    }

    //==================================================================
    // These events are raised when the server sends back a response
    //==================================================================
    function uploadComplete(evt) {

        alert(evt.target.responseText);
    }

    function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("Therew as an error attempting to upload the file.");
    }

    function uploadCancelled(evt) {
        alert("The upload has been cancelled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That worked like a charm. So one more question, since i just want to understand something here. When should i be worried about using the document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',... part whenever i'm coding?

Comment: Whenever you want to play with html contents at the start loading of the page you can call DOMContentLoaded event

Comment: Oh i see, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for the help and I'm not sure if I also thanked for the advice you gave me on another question i asked yesterday. Thank you!