# javascript submit lose $_POST value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#SoumettreCarte").submit(function(ev) {
    alert('ok');
    ev.preventDefault();

    ville="bonjour";

    $.post("../cartes/essai2.php", {ville:ville})
    .done(function (response) {
//         window.location.replace("http://localhost/projet2/cartes/essai2.php");

        });

 });
});
```

When i click on submit, i  want it to redirect me to essai2.php, so i use `window.location.replace`, but then i lose the value of my `$_POST`. So my problem, is how to load another page after submitting a form with javascript without losing my `$_POST`. Thanks for your help.

When i try action="essai2.php", i don't get "ville" in my $_POST.

Comment: So why are you using AJAX here? Why don't you use session or GET query parameters?

Comment: `window.location.replace()` will remove POST values.No need to give explict redirection. If you give file name in action attribute of form it will automatically redirect

Comment: Cant you just make the form action as essai2.php & just submit the form Jquery submit ? Why to use this window.location.replace ?

Comment: That's what tried to do, but then i don't get "ville" in my $_POST

Comment: Did you have an input named ville there ?  if you have a input variable by that name, you will get the values in essai2.php

Comment: can we see your HTMl ?

Comment: I have a form which will be filled by the user, and when submitted i want to send with it some information (which won't be filled by the user) such as "ville", but i didn't succeed.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/essai.js"></script>
<form   action="essai2.php" class ="SoumettreCarte" id="SoumettreCarte" method="post"  >
        <input type="text" name="pays" id="pays">
        <input type="submit"  name="submit" id="soumettre" value="soumettre la carte"  >
</form>

Comment: Then use hidden inputs to pass values such as ville

Comment: In my case, ville is a javascript variable and i don't know how to put it in an input value

Comment: you can give any name for input variable and use that name inside $_POST[''] to get its value

Answer (score 1):

You can make a hidden  field like this:

*HTML*

```
<input type="hidden" name="ville" id="ville">
```

You can change the input field's value like this:

*JQUERY*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ville = 'Bonjour';
  $("#ville").val(ville);
  //or $("[name=ville]").val(ville);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
<form action="essai2.php" class ="SoumettreCarte" id="SoumettreCarte" method="post" > 
<input type="text" name="pays" id="pays">
<input type="hidden" name="lat" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="lng" value=""> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="soumettre" value="soumettre la carte" > 
</form>
```

in jquery part do like this

```
var lat = "some lattitude";
var lng = "some longtitude";

$("[name=submit]").click(function(e){

$("[name=lat]").val(lat);
$("[name=lng]").val(lng);
});
```

Comment: ville is the latitude of the place (i get it with a javascript function), so it's a javascript variable and i don't know how to affect it to my input value.

Comment: With javascript i get 2 variables: latitude and longitude, I ask the user to fill a form and then i want to get the information added by the user, latitude and longitude in my $_POST.

Comment: I found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764154/pass-a-javascript-variable-value-into-input-type-hidden-value

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="essai2.php" class ="SoumettreCarte" id="SoumettreCarte" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="pays" id="pays">
<input type="hidden" name="lat" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lng" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="soumettre" value="soumettre la carte" >
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $.post("../cartes/essai2.php", data:$("#SoumettreCarte").serialize()) 
 .done(function (response) {

    });</script>
```

you  can try this one..