# return javascript function in JSP form

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a javascript function (get_deviceprint()) that return UI data such as ip, resolution, device, etc.  I need to return it as part of a form to the servlet.  I know the function works because `console.log(get_deviceprint());` correctly displays the info in the web console.

so the problem is passing this back as a string to the server.  I tried

```
<input type="hidden" name="devicePrint" value="<script type="text/javascript"> get_deviceprint()</script>"/>
```

but that returns `<script type=`.

I also tried `"return get_deviceprint()"`
but that returns `"return get_deviceprint()` literally.

so what should I put as the value?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about that. The reason your getting `<script type=` is because you are escaping quotes with the next `"`. Maybe try a single quote `'` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you're confused about a basic part of html, and programming languages in general: Contexts. html is constructed out of tags. A tag may contain attributes, which may have a value.

In a tree-like form:

```
tag
 | attribute = value
 | attribute
tag
 | attribute = value
tag
tag
 | attribute
...
```

Or more concretely:

```
<input type="password" hidden />
<img src="goat.png" />
<div>Blah</div>
```

When the browser (and you) go over a tag and try to understand it, it expects certain characters. it knows that `<` starts a tag, that `>` ends it, that after the `<` comes the tag name, and so forth. Going over some text and extracting meaning is called "parsing", and the rules you follow are called "grammar".

In our example above, the browser sees `<input type="password" hidden />`, and can break it down into the following:

```
<input type="password" hidden />
       ^-------------^ ^----^
          attr=value    attr
^------------------------------^
              tag
```

The html grammar does not allow you to specify a tag within an attribute's value. It just treats it like a regular value.

```
<input type="password" value="<div>blah</div>" />
       ^-------------^ ^---------------------^
          attr=value          attr=value
^-----------------------------------------------^
                       tag
```

When you think about it, it makes much more sense: What does it mean for a value to be a tag? What does `value="<div>blah</div>"` *do*? How do you make sense of it?

So we reach our problem: html is static, but you want to change it dynamically. Enter javascript and the DOM (Document Object Model):

```
var input = magically_get_the_input_element();
input.value = get_deviceprint();
```

The DOM is the result of parsing the html into objects you can interact with using javascript. That means that you can manipulate a page, which is exactly what you want. It's a big topic, and I won't endeavour to cover it in here, but here are some pointers to where you can learn about javascript and the DOM:

- [Intro to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) (Mozilla Developer Network)
- [Intro to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/Introduction) (MDN)
- [The javascript tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Comment: nice you are right. You have to use the document api:
  `var field2 = document.createElement("input");
  field2.setAttribute("type","hidden");
  field2.setAttribute("value",get_deviceprint());
  field2.setAttribute("name","devicePrint");
  document.instructionForm.appendChild(field2);
  document.instructionForm.submit();`

Comment: an alternative is to add an ID to the form as specified here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764154/pass-a-javascript-variable-value-into-input-type-hidden-value

Comment: Nice going, glad you got it!