# Pass javascript Word Count variable value as hidden field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple page:
http://jsfiddle.net/20140228/2cjw9h9n/1/

It uses this WordCount code as a starting point:
http://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/jZeKu/

But is much more basic, containing only the Word Count part of the code.

I need to pass the value of the wordCount Javascript variable to the "varCount" hidden form field variable.

I have looked at this page:
[Pass a javascript variable value into input type hidden value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764154/pass-a-javascript-variable-value-into-input-type-hidden-value)

But I can't work out how to implement the suggestions from the page into my page, as my Javascript understanding is rather basic!

I suppose it would have to include something like:

```
document.getElementById('varCount').value = ???;
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to pass value of your `wordCount` variable to your hidden field you can use this way:

```
$('#varCount').val(wordCount);
```

You need to write this into your `counter` function. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/xf4bxxa8/2/)**

(In demo i have changed hidden field to text field, just to show changes.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery

```
$('#varCount').val('your-value');
```

val can do a read or write operation on a particular DOM element simultaneously

`val()` - when called without a parameter reads the value of DOM element

`val('value')` - when called with a parameter writes the value to a DOM element

Answer (score 1):

I've a little bit modified your code.

```
<script>
setWordCount = function(wordCount){ 
    $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);

    // jQuery solution (this is what you actually need)
    $('#varCount').val(wordCount);

    // Commented below is plain JS solution (just in case you're curious)
    // document.getElementById('varCount').value = wordCount;
};

counter = function() {
    var value = $('#text').val();

    if (value.length == 0) {
        setWordCount(0);
    } else {
       var wordCount = value.trim().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length;
       setWordCount(wordCount);
    }
};

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#count').click(counter);
    // No need to have keypress, keydown, the keyup event will handle it anyway.
    $('#text').change(counter).keyup(counter).blur(counter).focus(counter);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
var abc;
abc = document.getElementById('wordCount').value;
<script>
```

The variable abc would get the value of the total number of words you have entered in the textarea.