# PayPal value from variable

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

What I want to do is to set PayPal button's "value" -attribute to my variable which I read from a JavaScript file.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="VARIABLE HERE">
```

It didn't work when I tried to add code like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<script>code here</script>">
```

Here is something that I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getPaypalPrice() {
        var finalPrice = getUrlVar()["totalprice"] * basePrice;
        return finalPrice;
    }
</script>
```

And then for the paypal button

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="paypalPrice" value="   <script>document.getElementById('paypalPrice').value = getPaypalPrice();</script>">
```

That did not work even when someone suggested that in a previous topic.
Is there any other solutions?

Comment: Please give a link to the question or answer that told you to put a script inside the double quotes of the value of an html element.

Comment: Very strange; I cannot find the topic anywhere... Not even from my history. It used <script> tags and there was a script that would count the price but those " quotes made it fail somehow. I can't describe it anymore because I cannot even find the topic lol.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764154/pass-a-javascript-variable-value-into-input-type-hidden-value?rq=1 this solution is not working for me either

Comment: Show us your code for that.

Comment: edited that to my original post

Comment: What you have posted does not match the answers in the question that you linked to. If you write your code like in those answers you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried another solution as well before but it didn't work (without <script> inside of those quotes. But now this is solved, thank you too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put any JavaScript or script tags in the `<input>`. This means in your HTML you have:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="paypalPrice" value="0">
```

Then in your JavaScript (either in a `<script>` tag or separate JS file) you can reference that input from its ID. Also note that the JavaScript should be loaded at the *bottom* of the page, so that the `#paypalPrice` element is already loaded into the browser before the JavaScript code runs.

```js
function getPaypalPrice() {
  console.log(getUrlVar().totalprice);  // check this has a value?
  return finalPrice = getUrlVar().totalprice * basePrice;
}

var paypalPriceElement = document.getElementById('paypalPrice');
paypalPriceElement.value = getPaypalPrice();
```

As I commented, please check your `getUrlVar()['totalprice']` is actually returning a value, since it could be asynchronous and causing you other issues.