# How to save an append with value in javascript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, methods, append

I have a problem here when I update the information, only the 'description' has updated the 'pullout_qty' did not. How can I save the 'pullout_qty' inside the append table? How am I supposed to update the value of 'pullout_qty' here?
I see a similar question [Pass a javascript variable value into input type hidden value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764154/pass-a-javascript-variable-value-into-input-type-hidden-value)  but the input hidden and value are inside the js.

```
function pullout_edit(x){
              $.post(URL+"index.php/pullout_request/loadPullOutRequestForm",{mode:'edit',pullout_id:pullout_id}).done(function(data){
                $("#dialog1").html(data).dialog("open");

                var description=$('#tbl_description'+x).val();
                $('#form_description').val(description);

                var product_name=$('#tbl_product_name'+x).val();
                var pullout_qty=$('#tbl_pending_pullout_qty'+x).val();

                $('#product_addtostock_toadd tbody').append(`
                    <tr id='tblC_row`+row_cnt+`'>
                    <td>
                    <input type='hidden' id='tblC_visibility`+row_cnt+`' value='1'/>
                    <input type='hidden' id='tblC_qty`+row_cnt+`' value='`+pullout_qty+`'/>
                    <td>`+product_name+`</td>
                    <td><input type='number' style='width:100%; border:none;' id='tblC_qty' min='1' value='`+pullout_qty+`'></td>
                    </tr>
                    `);

                $('#save').append(`
                    <div class='col-sm-12' align='right'>
                    <button class='btn btn-success' onclick='update_save();'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-save'></span> Update Request</button>
                    </div>
                    `);

}  //end edit
```

After saving the value of 'pullout_qty' becomes zero.

```
function update_save(){
        var cnt=parseInt($('#form_addstockcnt').val());

        var description=$('#form_description').val();
        var pullout_qty=[];
                        var z=0;
                        for(var x=0;x<cnt;x++){
                            if($('#tblC_visibility'+x).val()==1){                   
                                pullout_qty[z]=$('#tblC_qty'+x).val();
        z+=1;
    }
} 


        $.ajax({url:URL+"index.php/pullout_request/loadEditSave",
          method:"POST",
          data:{
            pullout_qty:pullout_qty,
            description:description,
        },
        success:function(data){
            SYS_pending_setlist();   
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#dialog1").dialog("close");     
            },500);
        },
        error:function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}  // end
```

Comment: Maybe nothing with the id `tbl_pending_pullout_qty` exists.  Try adding `alert(pullout_qty)` to check the value

Comment: It has value. I think the problem is inside the append()

Comment: I see a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764154/pass-a-javascript-variable-value-into-input-type-hidden-value

Comment: Sorry I can not understand the relevance of  two JS methods? Which one is wrong?

Comment: I solved it now. The problem was in update_save(). It should be var pullout_qty=$('#tblC_qty').val();