# Define function in script and call in input value comes undefined function

Tags: javascript, laravel

I called a function within script tag from an input value, but it throws Error -- **call to undefined function**
Here is the function definition

```
<script>
 function getSelectValue(sel){
    var lang=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
   

    return lang;
}
</script>
```

I called the function here

```
  <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" id="value" value="{{getSelectValue(this)}}" >

                    <label for="audiolang" class="input-label">Audio Language</label>
                        <select id="audio_lang" name="audio_lang" class="form-control " onchange="getSelectValue(this)">
                        <option selected disabled value="">Select Language</option>
                            <option value="1">English</option>
                            <option value="2">Arabic</option> 
                            <option value="3">Urdu</option>
                            <option value="4">Hindi</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Why this error **call to undefined function getSelectValue()** is coming.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: It should rather be `value="getSelectValue(this)"`. I doubt you want to run this function server-side

Comment: @Konrad `value="getSelectValue(this)"` won't execute any client-side JS either though; all that does is set the _literal_ text `getSelectValue(this)` as value for that field.

Comment: [Pass a javascript variable value into input type hidden value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764154/pass-a-javascript-variable-value-into-input-type-hidden-value)

Comment: exact error is Call to undefined function getSelectValue() (View: D:\Softwares\xampp6\htdocs\lms\resources\views\admin\webinars\modals\audio.blade.php)

Comment: I want to get the value of select  in hidden input value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you have `select` in your code and you want to get the selected value.

In select

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="setHiddenFieldValue(this)">
```

In input

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField">
```

In function

```
function setHiddenFieldValue(sel) {
    var lang = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(lang);
    document.getElementById("hiddenField").value = lang; // to set the value
}
```

Comment: I want to get the selected value in hidden input value

Comment: `document.getElementById("hiddenField").value = lang;` andd this instead of `console.log()`